# Run @nx/js:node executor with a performance profiler

Tags: node.js, typescript, esbuild

I have an application which runs a node app using [NX](https://nx.dev/). I'm not all too familier with either technologies, but I want to run a profiler on the code to see which parts of the code take up the most time. Google quickly takes me to some simple [examples](https://nodejs.org/en/guides/simple-profiling). However, we are using NX, and I would like a configuration to run this profiler easily.
Our NX config looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "search-api",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/search-api/src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nx/esbuild:esbuild",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "defaultConfiguration": "production",
      "options": {
        "platform": "node",
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/search-api",
        "format": ["cjs"],
        "bundle": false,
        "main": "apps/search-api/src/main.ts",
        "tsConfig": "apps/search-api/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "apps/search-api/cert",
            "output": "./cert"
          }
        ],
        "generatePackageJson": true,
        "esbuildOptions": {
          "sourcemap": true,
          "outExtension": {
            ".js": ".js"
          }
        }
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {},
        "production": {
          "generateLockfile": true,
          "esbuildOptions": {
            "sourcemap": false,
            "outExtension": {
              ".js": ".js"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nx/js:node",
      "defaultConfiguration": "development",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "search-api:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "search-api:build:development"
        },
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "search-api:build:production"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```